# Spring Boot PasswordEncoder class file not found

Tags: java, spring-boot

This error just doesn't allow me run my program further.
How to fix this problem? Should I add some other libraries? Problem is about passwordEncoder.

Error is:

> Error:(77, 52) java: cannot access org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder
>     class file for org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder not found

```
package com.example.attendance;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration","/img/**","/js/**","/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**","/admin").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html. You're not using the correct package (assuming you'reusing the current version of spring security).

Comment: Are you using maven? If so, what is in your POM.

Answer (score 0):

add this authenticationmanager bean to this class

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```